# CTCLoss in Tensorflow saying indices out of bounds

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using the TIMIT corpus for using MFCC data as inputs and phoneme Labels(with phoneme values converted to integers) as target outputs.
I am trying to create a sparse tensor from the phoneme labels available for making use of the Tensorflow CTC function.

The error that I am receiving is:

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): label SparseTensor is not valid: indices[1] = [1,0] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [1,9]
     [[Node: CTCLoss = CTCLoss[ctc_merge_repeated=true, preprocess_collapse_repeated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](transpose_1, _recv_targets/indices_0, _recv_targets/values_0, _recv_sequence_length_0)]]`

Unable to find the solution to this. Have my made any error of dimensions or something else?

The code for the program is here:
https://github.com/shardulparab97/Speech-Recog/blob/master/model2.py

- The size of input_val is (1,9,13)
- The function sparse_tuple_from to give the inputs to the CTC function is:

`def sparse_tuple_from(sequences, dtype=np.int32):
    #Create a sparse representention of x.
    #Args:
    #    sequences: a list of lists of type dtype where each element is a #sequence
    #Returns:
    #    A tuple with (indices, values, shape)
    #
    indices = []
    values = []
    #print ("SEQUENCES IN FUNCTION:",sequences)
    for n, seq in enumerate(sequences):
        indices.extend(zip([n] * len(matrix(seq)), range(len(matrix(seq)))))
        values.extend([seq])
    indices = np.asarray(indices, dtype=np.int32)
    values = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
    shape = np.asarray([len(sequences), np.asarray(indices).max(0)[1] + 1], dtype=np.int32)
    return indices, values, shape`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question,I change the maxtimesteps,and that works.So,you should change your timesteps to a larger number